# Store the index of audio in shared preferences

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have a listview of ringtone with a bookmark icon in each row inside my main Fragment. And I have another fragment to show the favorited ringtones inside it.
When I click on one item to mark it as favorite it will work fine and the selected item will successfully add to my favorite list Fragment. But the problem is this is not working for the ringtones (`songID`). For example, if I select item #2 it will add Item #2 in favorite Fragment, but it will play the first audio raw.

in my **Main Fragment**

```
private final int[] songID = { R.raw.aaa, R.raw.bbb, R.raw.ccc}; 

private List<ProductLight> songList = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();

    ProductLight product1 = new ProductLight(1,"Song Title 1");
    ProductLight product2 = new ProductLight(2,"Song Title 2");
    ProductLight product3 = new ProductLight(3,"Song Title 3");

    songList = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();
    songList.add(product1);
    songList.add(product2);
    songList.add(product3);
```

add to favorite logic:

```
    @Override
public boolean favOnClick(int position , View v) {
    ProductLight product = songList.get(position);
    ImageView button = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.favImageHive);
    String tag = button.getTag().toString();
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
        sharedPreference.addFavorite(product);
        snackS("Added to Favorites");
        button.setTag("red");
        button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
    } else {
        sharedPreference.removeFavorite(product);
        button.setTag("grey");
        button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
        snackS("Removed from Favorites");
    }

    return true;
}
```

And in my **Favorite Fragment**

```
private final int[] songID = { R.raw.aaa, R.raw.bbb, R.raw.ccc}; 

private List<ProductLight> songList = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();

songList = sharedPreference.getFavorites();
```

**Shared Preferences**

```
public class SharedPreference_light {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Light_Products";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite_Tones_Light";

SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Gson gson = new Gson();

public SharedPreference_light(Context context) {
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
}

// This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
public void saveFavorites(List<ProductLight> favorites) {
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
    editor.apply();
}

public void addFavorite(ProductLight product) {
    List <ProductLight> favorites = getFavorites();
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();
    favorites.add(product);
    saveFavorites(favorites);
    Log.w("addPrefLog", favorites.toString());
}

public void removeFavorite(ProductLight product) {
    ArrayList <ProductLight> favorites = getFavorites();
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(product);
        saveFavorites(favorites);
    }
}

public ArrayList <ProductLight> getFavorites() {
    List<ProductLight> favorites;
    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        ProductLight[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, ProductLight[].class);
        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList <ProductLight> (favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList <ProductLight> ) favorites;
    }
 }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class ProductLight {

private String title;
private int id;
private ArrayList<String> genre;

public ProductLight(int id,String name,ArrayList<String> genre){
    this.title = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public boolean paused = true;

private String Tag;
public String getTag() {
    return Tag;
}
public void setTag(String tag) {
    Tag = tag;
}

private int favId;
public int getFavId() {
    return favId;}
public void setFavId(int favId) {
    this.favId = favId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}
public int getYear() {
    return id;
}
public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ProductLight other = (ProductLight) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + title + ", genre="
            + genre + "]";
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make it right, can you help me, please?

Comment: can you add code of method sharedPreference.addFavorite here

Comment: in ProductLight first value is integer is that index of song? If yes this should start from 0 if not then what is the use of it.

Comment: @Avi those are  the id of the tones, You mean I should add another int for the ringtones in ProductLight constructor !?

Comment: Which Id? where did you get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned:

> When I click on one item to mark it as favorite it will work fine and the selected item will successfully add to my favorite list Fragment.

Then try to add another parameter as audio resources to your `ProductLight`

```
    private int res;
    public int getRes() {
    return res;
}

public ProductLight(..... int res){
this.res= res;
```

}

And add them to your list

```
ProductLight product1 = new ProductLight(1,"Song Title 1, R.raw.youraudio1");
ProductLight product2 = new ProductLight(2,"Song Title 2, R.raw.youraudio2");
ProductLight product3 = new ProductLight(3,"Song Title 3, R.raw.youraudio3");
```